# Underscore template does not render element on Backbone View re-render

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having a very perplexing issue which I've never seen before. I wonder if I'm missing something very obvious.

I have an template like so (which I compile with [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)):

```
<a href="#advanced-search" data-toggle="modal">
  Advanced search
</a>

<div id="advanced-search">
  <div class="modal-header">header</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="advanced-search-form">
      // This has form elements
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that whenever I re-render the Backbone View which is using the template, the form element is not rendered! The initial render works fine.

I've tried separating the form element from the `advanced-search-form` id by nesting a `<div id="advanced-search-form">` within the form element and removing the id from the form element. The result is that the nested `div` is rendered while the `form` still is not.

I need the form element in order to use `serializeArray`, which [only works on form elements](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serializeArray#overview).

I suppose a workaround would be to write a function which can serialize input elements within *any* element, but this is not ideal and I would really like to discover why this strange thing is happening.

Thanks for looking!

EDIT: the render code
Right now I am not re-rendering based on any collection or model events. I am manually triggering the re-render via a click event on a link in the parent view. The following is the basic structure of my two views (CoffeeScript):

```
AdvancedSearchView = Backbone.View.extend
  template: _.template AdvancedSearchTpl   #available via requirejs      

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template() 

ParentView = Backbone.View.extend
  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll @
    $('body #refresh').livequery 'click', @refreshAdvancedSearch

  render: ->
    if !@advancedSearchElem #cache the view to save state
      @advancedSearchView = new AdvancedSearchView
      @advancedSearchElem = @advancedSearchView.render().el
    $('#content').html @advancedSearchElem

  refreshAdvancedSearch: ->
    @advancedSearchElem = @advancedSearchView.render().el  #from here, the template is rendered without the form element
    @render()

parentView = new ParentView
parentView.render()
```

Comment: What's the code doing the rendering look like?

Comment: Add a `<% debugger %>` to the start of your template, and using your favorite Browser's debugger, step through the generated template code.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in JSFiddle? Here's a ready fiddle with Backbone, underscore etc. already loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/3ekqd/

Comment: @fencliff I've tried to reproduce the error to no avail. Will try again...

Comment: @WiredPrairie The generated template code seems to contain the form element, initially and during subsequent renders.

Comment: So I've changed the assignment to `@advancedSearchElem` in `ParentView::refreshAdvancedSearch` to read: `@advancedSearchElem = null` and let the `ParentView::render` handle reinstantiating the view (I know, not the same functionality, but similar). Something wonky was going on -- I'm still not sure what, but it seems to work now........ Also, this question may be too localized to be helpful for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Later on I realized I was rendering a `<form>` inside another `form` tag, and I believe Chrome automatically fixed the invalid html by removing the inner `form` tag. This was probably my issue, as `console.logging` the html output of the template included the inner form tag.